# MATLAB: Finding statistics of sorted data using vectorization

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have some functional code that I'm trying to speed up by eliminating the for loop.

I have a set of data in x,y pairs as two vectors, so x(k) and y(k) form a pair.  I also have a set of bin edges (xe).  For every bin j, there is a set of x values in that bin, defined by xe(j) <= x(k) < xe(j+1). For each bin, I would like to find the mean and standard deviation of all y(k) with x(k) in that bin.

MATLAB code that accomplishes this is below:

```
[meany, standardeviation] = ystatsvsx (xdata, ydata, xe)

meany = zeros([size(ydata,1) (length(xe)-1)]);
standarddeviation = meany;   
[numx,bin] = histc(xdata, xe);
for j = 1:(length(xe) - 1)
   inds = bin == j;
   meany(j) = mean(ydata(inds));
   standarddeviation(j) = std(ydata(inds));
end
```

When xe is large, this function becomes slow.  Does anyone have any suggestiosn about how to vectorize this code to eliminate the for loop?  The number of data points in a given bin (numx) is variable.

One caveat: length(xe)*length(xdata) in these cases is very large (length(xdata) is always much larger than length(xe)), so it is not possible to use repmat to create a length(xe) x length(xdata) matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `accumarray` to do that. Try something like that:

```
meany = accumarray(bin(:),ydata(:),[],@mean);
standarddeviation = accumarray(bin(:),ydata(:),[],@std);
```